# El proyecto es multiempresa y lo que quiero conseguir es que cada cliente tenga su propia base de datos con codeigniter 4

Tags: php8, codeigniter-4

Tengo un proyecto hecho en codeigniter. El proyecto es multiempresa y lo que quiero conseguir es que cada cliente tenga su propia base de datos.

La idea que tengo para esto es que en función del usuario que acceda a la web, el programa utilice una base de datos u otra.

Logro cambiar la configuración y establecer conexión a esa base de datos, pero cuando el usuario intenta iniciar sesión no puedo lograr realizar la consulta a la tabla de su base de datos.

```
// Cambiar la conexión de la base de datos según el usuario
public function cambiarConexion($database)
{
    // Establece la nueva conexión
    try {
        // Accede a la configuración de la base de datos
        $dbConfig = config('Database');

        $config = $dbConfig->miConfig;

        $config['database'] = $database;

        $conexion = Database::connect($config);

        return $conexion;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Luego intento realizar eso, pero no logro que funcione, sale que la base de datos no seleccionada

```
namespace App\Models;

  use CodeIgniter\Model;

  class ClienteModel extends Model
  {
    protected $DBGroup          = 'miConfig';
    protected $table            = 'cliente';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'id_cliente';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $returnType       = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes   = false;
    protected $protectFields    = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = [
        'id_cliente',
        'nombre',
        'fecha_registro'
    ];

    // Dates
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $dateFormat    = 'datetime';
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

    // Validation
    protected $validationRules      = [];
    protected $validationMessages   = [];
    protected $skipValidation       = false;
    protected $cleanValidationRules = true;

    // Callbacks
    protected $allowCallbacks = true;
    protected $beforeInsert   = [];
    protected $afterInsert    = [];
    protected $beforeUpdate   = [];
    protected $afterUpdate    = [];
    protected $beforeFind     = [];
    protected $afterFind      = [];
    protected $beforeDelete   = [];
    protected $afterDelete    = [];

    public function getClientes()
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
        $builder->select('*');
        $query = $builder->get();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
  }
```